# Set one of several available classes to Json DeserializeObject via code

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7

I have several classes

```
public class JsonWorldRanking
{
    public int no { get; set; }
    public string deviceid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int clicks { get; set; }
    public int country { get; set; }
}

public class JsonNationalRanking
{
    public int no { get; set; }
    public string deviceid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int clicks { get; set; }
}

public class JsonCountryRanking
{
    public int no { get; set; }
    public int countryIndexRanking { get; set; }
    public int clicks { get; set; }
}
```

I want to select any one of those three classes for Json deserialized operation based on certain condition. So if using switch case for instance, how do I make WHICHLASS below represents the correct class? Something like

```
switch value

{
  case 0:
  WHICHCLASS = JsonWorldRanking;
  break;

  case 1:
  WHICHCLASS = JsonNationalRanking;
  break;

  case 2:
  WHICHCLASS = JsonCountryRanking
  break;
}

...

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WHICHCLASS>>(r.EventArgs.Result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to create generic method of T. But this will work too

```
Type destinationType = null;

switch value

{
  case 0:
  destinationType  = typeof(JsonWorldRanking);
  break;

  case 1:
  destinationType  = typeof(JsonNationalRanking);
  break;

  case 2:
  destinationType  = typeof(JsonCountryRanking);
  break;
}

...

Type listType = typeof(List<>);
Type[] typeArgs = {destinationType};
type requiredGenericListType = listType.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);

var deserialized = JsonConvert.Deserialize(r.EventArgs.Result, requiredGenericListType );
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I get

    namespace.class.destinationType is a field but used like a type

Comment: How do I create dynamic method of T for the class?

Comment: You should probably use this overload of deserialize http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ee191864(v=vs.110).aspx